# Iappcompat v21: material design ActionBar() InflateException error-inflating-class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, fragment, android-appcompat

Trying to move app made in (`appcompat v20`) to the new library `appcompat v21`

with: `appcompat-v7:20` work nice

I did this:

```
ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, ActionBar.OnNavigationListener
```

and have this:

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout`

[Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386077/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-internal-widget-actionbarview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was much deeper than it seems.

My code was correct. All the advice in the subject relevant and correct.

It turned out that external libraries contain old versions `support-v4`, which does **not support** `MATERIAL DESIGN(appcompat-v7:21)` but only `appcompat-v7:20`

It was the reason for `ActionBar() InflateException error-inflating-class.`

Update `support-v4` in all **external** libraries will solve the problem.

My build.gradle in other topic:

[multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888089/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4).

Answer (score 11):

In order to use the new `appcompat v21` you have to:

- extend the `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`
- use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`
- use a theme which inherits from *Theme.AppCompat*.(for example Light or NoActionBar)

**EDIT: 23/04/2015**

With the new `appcompat v22.1` you should use the new `AppCompatActivity` instead of the `ActionBarActivity`

Also, ActionBar.TabListener, ActionBar.OnNavigationListener: Action bar navigation modes are deprecated **and not supported by inline toolbar action bars.** Consider using other common navigation patterns instead.

Source doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#addTab(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab)

Comment: @user3871754 post your layout with the toolbar

Comment: sorry wrong messages, check my answer exception again

here in my all source code: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: This might also help you to solve this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26738677/1304830

Comment: Now that ActionBarActivity is deprecated on v22 you should use AppCompatActivity instead

Answer (score 4):

this is working code...copmactv7_api5 using...another steps are same

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin_main_tab);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections
    // of the app.
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener
    // for when the
    // user swipes between sections.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // When swiping between different app sections, select
                    // the corresponding tab.
                    // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if
                    // we have a reference to the
                    // Tab.
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the
        // TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the primary sections of the app.
 */
public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new AdminSettings();
        default:
            Fragment fragment = new AdminSettings();
            return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Section " + (position + 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: What's in your `R.id.pager`?


`<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`