# multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-manifest, android-support-library

I can not compile the project gets the following error compilation:

Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Android Studio\Android Studio\myApp\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\myApp\Downloads\Android Studio\Android Studio\myApp\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\libraryList.txt
>       Error Code:
>           2
>       Output:
>           UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>           com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>               at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)

Of course, this code solve my problem

`configurations {
      all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'`

but unfortunately does not satisfy me

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    compile project(':PullToRefreshListFragment')
    compile project(':validator')
    compile project(':AndroidBootstrap')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'

    compile 'com.github.codechimp-org.apprater:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.71.0'

    compile ('com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6')
    {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile ('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:2.+')
    {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'gms:play-services')
    }
    configurations {
      // all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

    }
```

how can I compile the project?

Comment: I think there are different versions of support v4 being referenced. If you and your dependencies all reference the same version, it will compile without problems.

Comment: Of course you're right and I know that.
But how to force the latest version of the support-v4 library for all conflicts?

Comment: If some of your libraries (android-async-http, crouton, smartlocation) are including support library classes, then they are mispackaged and the library authors should fix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the library authors should fix them

Comment: Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: If some of your libraries (android-async-http, crouton, smartlocation) are including support library classes, then they are mispackaged and the library authors should fix them. there are different versions of support v4 being referenced. If you and your dependencies all reference the same version, it will compile without problems.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a common ADT to Android studio migration problem. ADT is looking for a copy of android-support-v4.jar in the libs/ dir while Android studio has it's own internal copy. When migrating the jar file is left in the libs dir which creates a duplicate jar most likely an older version. I deleted the jar in the libs dir and problem was solved.

Comment: But how did you deleted the jar file?

Comment: just delete the file and re-sync android studio + clean build.