# actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) deprecated

Tags: java, android

I'm following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVahIc8yENk and I'm getting the error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object
>   reference

I'm using Android Studio to write this program and I have tried from API 11 to 21 and none of them work.

```
public class Tabtest extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_test);

        actionBar=getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("tab1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("tab2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("tab3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab4=actionBar.newTab();
        tab4.setText("tab4");
        tab4.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);
        actionBar.addTab(tab4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.d("VIVZ", "onTabReselected at "+" position "+tab.getPosition()+" name "+tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.d("VIVZ", "onTabReselected at "+" position "+tab.getPosition()+" name "+tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.d("VIVZ", "onTabReselected at "+" position "+tab.getPosition()+" name "+tab.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for `getActionBar()`?

Comment: This answer may be helpful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480626/appcompat-v21-material-design-actionbar-inflateexception-error-inflating-clas

Answer (score 10):

I was following Vivz example in youtube but when the method deprecated i had to find another way. Instead of adding tabs to the actionbar try:

**Modify your adapter:**

```
public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private String[] titles = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };

    public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i){
          case 0:
             return new FragmentA();
          case 1:
             return new FragmentB();
          case 2:
             return new FragmentC();        
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }
}
```

And in the activity that you would like to implement the tabs try

```
public class Tabtest extends ActionBarActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_test);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.your_view_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new CollectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

Now if you would like to style your tabs like Google Play store with a moving indicator under the tab name and move while the user scrolls compile this library

```
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
```

And modify your viewpager layout file like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  //obviously add width and height and other necessery stuff
  android:orientation="vertical">

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And then you are going to have the desired effect.

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 4):

you can use "**PagerSlidingTabStrip**"  replacing  "**setNavigationMode**"

[here a tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip)
and  here a [example](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) in Github

Answer (score 1):

finally i found answer.
1st your android sdk

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
```

it must higher than 11.
2nd
your theme must have actionbar like

```
android:theme="Theme.AppCompat"
```

3rd 
don't use  this code in your activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

4th
instead of `import android.support.v4.app.ActionBar` use `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` in your activity

5th
change this `actionBar=getActionBar();` to `actionbar=getSupportActionBar();`

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
```

Your theme apparently is one that does not have an action bar. Since you are not using `appcompat-v7`, make sure that you are using a theme that supports the native action bar, such as one of the `Theme.Holo` series.

If, instead, you are trying to use `appcompat-v7`, you need to inherit from `ActionBarActivity` and you need to use `getSupportActionBar()`, not `getActionBar()`.

Also note that action bar tabs were deprecated as of Android 5.0. You should consider another tab solution, such as the combination of `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip`.

Comment: when I made the project i saw nothing about a theme so how do i select one ? and also could you send me a tutorial for the combination of ViewPager and PagerTabStrip

Comment: @RashaadBryan: "so how do i select one ?" -- look for `android:theme` attributes in your manifest, in the `<application>` and/or `<activity>` elements.

Comment: @RashaadBryan: With regards to `ViewPager` and `PagerTitleStrip`, here is a sample app from my book: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Indicator  There are probably some tutorials floating around that you might find via a search engine.

Comment: i check under styles and i have the theme <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> which has an actionbar so there shouldnt an error ? @CommonsWare

Comment: @RashaadBryan: If you are going to use something based on `Theme.AppCompat`, you need to inherit from `ActionBarActivity` and use `getSupportActionBar()`, not `getActionBar()`.

Comment: i tried that put i still get the same problem setNavigationMode is deprecated @CommonsWare

Comment: @RashaadBryan: "setNavigationMode is deprecated" -- yes, I mentioned that at the end of my answer. There is nothing that you can do to make it be not deprecated, unless you can go back in time. Your choices are either to live with the deprecation warning or use another tab solution.