# ActionBar Tabs won't disappear on Fragment transactions

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer that links three fragments. All fragments have an ActionBar with different titles. Fragment A and B have no tabs, while Fragment C has tab 1 and tab 2. Navigating through them works fine and shows different ActionBar titles, but when I navigate from C to the other fragments, the tabs are still displayed in Fragment A and B's ActionBar. How do I "hide" the tabs when am navigating from C to Fragment A and B ?

Thanks

Switching between fragments

```
switch (possition) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentB();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentC();
            break;

             default: 
            break;
         }
         FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
```

Fragment C

```
 private String[] tabs = { "1", "2"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_utilities, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(UtilitiesFragment.this));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply setting your navigation mode to be the non-tabbed variety...

```
setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

...and then setting it back to the tabbed mode when relevant.

Another option is to simply remove the tabs via the `removeTab` method on the `ActionBar` and then add them back again when relevant.

One thing to note is that this navigation method has been deprecated as of API level 21 and it is [recommended that you use a different approach/pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).

Comment: using 'setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);' on non tab fragments and 'setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)' on the fragment with tabs worked. For now I can use it as a temporary fix but I would like to know how I can hide tabs for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27729494/3729235)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the second time I'm suggesting this today:Use a TabLayout inside the fragment instead of the ActionBar tabs.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html