# Action bar problems implementing swipe views with android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a swipe view as described here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

I've created an action bar as per the documentation with `final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();`

but I get the following message

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object
>   reference

which relates to this line         `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

Now i've established that it's likely to do with my theme not having an action bar, see `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`, so I change my theme to say `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">`, but then I get the following message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead

and all the answers on the internet say to change to a non action bar theme, which gives me the first error again. So I'm literally going around in circles. I want to basically have this action bar with tabs as described in the documentation.

Comment: Keep the no action bar theme. Make sure to set your toolbar as the support action bar.

Comment: So I switch to that theme but I get that state exception. I'm creating the toolbar with final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This theme already has `ActionBar`:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

And of course, you are trying to use the old `ActionBar` with `AppCompat` theme.

So, you will need to use `Theme.Holo` for that the old `ActionBar` or if you are using `Theme.AppCompat`, you need to use it with `getSupportActionBar` like this:

```
actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Check this question: [actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726759/actionbar-setnavigationmodeactionbar-navigation-mode-tabs-deprecated)