# java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme - while using the AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I have this exception for one user in production, it does not happen on my local builds on all the phones I tried and I cannot see what is wrong with my configuration.

Stack trace looks like:

```
Message: IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.m in SourceFile::2309
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.a in SourceFile::252
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView in SourceFile::109
my.package.HomeFragmentActivity.onCreate in SourceFile::80
```

My theme is defined as:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

And my manifest is:

```
    <application
    android:name="my.package.Application"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/my_logo"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
    <activity android:name="my.package.HomeFragmentActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Looking at the source for [AppCompatDelegateImplV7](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java), this exception is thrown if `windowActionBar` is not present in the theme, which it sure looks like it is when I browse the hierarchy of the Theme.AppCompat.Light theme.

This is slightly older branch where the activity actually extends the deprecated `ActionBarActivity` not `AppCompatActivity`, but it seems to just use `AppCompatActivity` behind the scenes either way.

App Compat v23.0.1 and the user is running on a Samsung S4 on 5.0.1.

What could be going on here?

**EDIT** My question is different from the linked "duplicate" question because in that question the OP was not using the Theme.AppCompat theme, while I am using the Theme.AppCompat theme.

Comment: You should show `HomeFragmentActivity`. It seems like it `extends` `FragmentActivity` and it should extend `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: @Gonzalo - it extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

Comment: @CyprienAubry - different issue. I am using the AppCompat theme in mine, the OP in the SO post you linked to was not.

Comment: Change it to extends AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of time spent on this, I've conclueed that there is nothing my code is doing wrong and I am going to hope that this is a bug in the older version of the support library and how it interacts with the specific phone.

Hoping that the upgrade to the latest support library version will make this rare issue go away for that one user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using androidx libraries then this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53749686/6883143

update from

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```