# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme error, even with theme set to AppCompat

Tags: java, android, xml, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am busy trying to implement The support library so that i can make use of `AppCompatActivty`

As far as I know I have everything in the correct place. But I am still getting the error.

styles.xml

```
<resources>        
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">            
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>       
</resources>
```

v21/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>     
</resources>
```

manifest.xml

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_on"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

activity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Now when I run my application and try open `RegisterActivty` I get the following error.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tuta_me/activities.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I must have missed something somewhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">            
</style>
```

in your **v21/styles.xml** file. Without it, `<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">` has no meaning.

Comment: Does it not extend the AppBaseTheme from the standard styles.xml

Comment: No it does not. Each `styles.xml` file for each **API level**.

Comment: did that, and still getting the error. I have edited the v21 styles block in my initial question to reflect how it is now with your addition.

Comment: Can you update your question with the whole **manifest.xml** file ?

Comment: Just post it, so that we could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, maybe helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53749686/6883143
This answer looks like:

I have same problem when I've migrate to androidx. I've solve this by simply updating from

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```